# awk or sed to place space after three matching patterns with some exception

Tags: awk, sed

I am looking forward to Match all the three pattern from the command and place a space , it should be continue with all 3 matchig pattern with the entire output received but in case if it gets only the first match it did not get rest two then don't print that single match at all ....

Below is the real command output from which i want to get this, where if you see first match "dn" searched and it don't contain othe 2 patterns of search.
at the same time it would be great it we can have awk or sed itself in place of grep itself ...

```
$ ldapsearch -h myldapserver -x -LLL -b "ou=profile,o=ferry.com" "cn=*" | grep -Ei "^dn|defaultServerList|preferredServerList"
    dn: cn=proxyagent,ou=profile,o=ferry.com
    dn: cn=default,ou=profile,o=ferry.com
    preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
    defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.27
    dn: cn=austin, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
    defaultServerList: 192.68.63.10 10.209.208.23
    preferredServerList: 192.68.88.14 10.28.15.10
    dn: cn=sanjose, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
    preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
    defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.38
```

Expected output is :

```
dn: cn=proxyagent,ou=profile,o=ferry.com  (--> This is single matched found without 2 others, which i don't want to be printed if its alone without 2 others)

dn: cn=default,ou=profile,o=ferry.com
preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.27

dn: cn=austin, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
defaultServerList: 192.68.63.10 10.209.208.23
preferredServerList: 192.68.88.14 10.28.15.10

dn: cn=sanjose, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.38
```

> 2) Though i'm able to place the space after every 3 occurance with sed
>   & awk as below..

```
$ ldapsearch -h myldapserver -x -LLL -b "ou=profile,o=ferry.com" "cn=*" | egrep  "^dn|defaultServerList|preferredServerList" | sed '0~3 a\\'

$ ldapsearch -h myldapserver -x -LLL -b "ou=profile,o=ferry.com" "cn=*" | egrep  "^dn|defaultServerList|preferredServerList" |awk ' {print;} NR % 3 == 0 { print ""; }'

   dn: cn=proxyagent,ou=profile,o=ferry.com
   dn: cn=default,ou=profile,o=ferry.com
   preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16

    defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.27
    dn: cn=austin, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
    defaultServerList: 192.68.63.10 10.209.208.23

    preferredServerList: 192.68.88.14 10.28.15.10
```

=================================================================

actual command output:

```
$ ldapsearch -h myldapserver -x -LLL -b "ou=profile,o=ferry.com" "cn=*"

dn: cn=proxyagent,ou=profile,o=ferry.COM
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fTBmVVVjSTI1SDZINS4=
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
sn: proxyagent
cn: proxyagent

dn: cn=default,ou=profile,o=ferry.COM
preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.27
objectClass: top
bindTimeLimit: 10
credentialLevel: proxy
cn: default
profileTTL: 120

dn: cn=austin, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
defaultServerList: 192.68.63.10 10.209.208.23
preferredServerList: 192.68.88.14 10.28.15.10
attributeMap: printers:printer-uri-supported=printer-xri-supported
objectClass: top
objectClass: DUAConfigProfile
objectClass: kdsdirobjectinfo
description: Austin Default Profile
```

> **3) Answer complied based on the input from you guys, may be usable for some other folks at some point of time! Appreciate all your Inputs & Suggestions**

```
$ cat ldaphostprofile.sh
#!/bin/bash
#Author : karn Kumar (08/02/2017)
# This is Just to check what is are prefered Ldap server's and default for authentication by sitewise
# There is contribution from some of folks over open forums
# s=1; s*=2; s*=3 here using math, the value s will be divisible by 6 only if both 2 and 3 factors are there, here multiple occurrences won't change the condition but only the latest values encountered are used.

# s && !(s%6) checks for divisibility by 6 and whether value is initialized in "dn" check.

# s=0 reset value after printing, so that printing will be suspended until the next group.

# sep you want the triples separated by an empty line, we don't want to add after every group, since it will leave an empty line at the end, or similarly at the beginning. Alternative is, using a late initialized variable (after first use). So there won't be an empty line at the beginning or the end, but in between groups.
# mapfile is bash build in function can be used with BASH Version >= 4.0 onwards

set -f      # to prevent filename expansion

mapfile -t PLIST < <(ldapsearch -h myldapserver -x -LLL -b "ou=profile,o=ferry.com" "cn=*" | awk '/^dn/ {s =1; dn=$0} /^preferredServerList/ {s*=2; ps=$0}/^defaultServerList/ {s*=3; ds=$0} s && !(s%6) {print sep dn ORS ps ORS ds; sep=ORS; s=0}' | awk '/preferredServerList/ { print $2,$3,$4 }')

mapfile -t DLIST < <(ldapsearch -h myldapserver -x -LLL -b "ou=profile,o=ferry.com" "cn=*" | awk '/^dn/ {s =1; dn=$0} /^preferredServerList/ {s*=2; ps=$0}/^defaultServerList/ {s*=3; ds=$0} s && !(s%6) {print sep dn ORS ps ORS ds; sep=ORS; s=0}' | awk '/defaultServerList/ { print $2,$3,$4 }')

mapfile -t LLIST < <(ldapsearch -h myldapserver -x -LLL -b "ou=profile,o=ferry.com" "cn=*" | awk '/^dn/ {s =1; dn=$0} /^preferredServerList/ {s*=2; ps=$0}/^defaultServerList/ {s*=3; ds=$0} s && !(s%6) {print sep dn ORS ps ORS ds; sep=ORS; s=0}' | awk '/dn/ {print $2}'| cut -d "," -f1 | cut -d"=" -f2)

count_x=${#PLIST[@]}
count_y=${#DLIST[@]}
count_l=${#LLIST[@]}

echo $count_x
echo $count_y
echo $count_l

# Find out which of the two is larger in size, assuming that's a possibility
if [[ $count_x -lt $count_y ]]
  then
    count=$count_y
else
  count=${count_x}
#elif
# count=${count_l}
fi

printf "=%.0s"  $(seq 1 150)
printf "\n"
printf "%-50s : %-50s : %-50s\n"         "PreferredList IP's"  "DefaultServerList IP's"   "Location"            # print header
printf "=%.0s"  $(seq 1 150)                                                                                    # print separator
printf "\n"                                                                                                     # print newline

for i in $(seq $count);
do
  printf "%-50s : %-50s : %-50s\n"  "${PLIST[i-1]}"    "${DLIST[i-1]}" "${LLIST[i-1]}"
done

[root ~/SCRIPTS]$ ./ldaphostprofile.sh
455
455
455
======================================================================================================================================================
PreferredList IP's                                 : DefaultServerList IP's                             : Location
======================================================================================================================================================
192.218.88.14 10.28.15.10                           : 192.20.63.10 10.209.208.23                         : austin
192.168.8.15 192.168.8.16                            : 192.168.8.15 192.168.8.16 192.218.88.38           : sanjose
192.168.8.15 192.168.8.16                            : 192.168.8.16 192.168.8.15                            : India
192.162.167.9 192.162.167.8                          : 192.168.8.16 192.218.88.38                           : japan
192.162.167.9 192.162.167.8                          : 192.168.8.15 192.218.88.38                           : China
192.162.167.9 192.162.167.8                          : 192.168.8.16 192.218.88.38                           :  Franse
192.162.167.9 192.162.167.8                          : 192.168.8.16 192.168.8.15                            :  Brazil
192.168.8.16 192.168.8.15 192.168.8.6                 : 192.168.8.16 192.218.88.38                          :  Tiwan
192.168.8.15 192.168.8.16                            : 192.168.8.15 192.218.88.38                           :  Russia
192.162.167.9 192.162.167.8                          : 192.168.8.16 192.218.88.38                           :  Germany
192.133.208.24 192.135.200.10                        : 192.135.200.10 172.23.39.200                        :   Poland
```

Comment: If you want a script to operate on the output of ldapsearch then show us the output of ldapsearch, not the output of that piped to some other command that you don't want. In other words, just show us sample input for the command you want to create so we're not guessing at what that might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ... | awk 'NR>1 && /^dn/{print ""} /^dn|(preferred|default)ServerList/' file
```

should do.  To print only groups of three, you have to add little more logic

```
$ awk '/^dn/                  {s =1; dn=$0} 
       /^preferredServerList/ {s*=2; ps=$0} 
       /^defaultServerList/   {s*=3; ds=$0} 
       s && !(s%6)            {print sep dn ORS ps ORS ds; sep=ORS; s=0}' file
```

**Notes**

> `s=1; s*=2; s*=3` here using math, the value `s` will be divisible by 6 only if both 2 and 3 factors are there, here multiple occurrences won't change the condition but only the latest values encountered are used.
>
> `s && !(s%6)` checks for divisibility by 6 and whether value is initialized in "dn" check.
>
> `s=0` reset value after printing, so that printing will be suspended until the next group.
>
> `sep` you want the triples separated by an empty line,  we don't want to add after every group, since it will leave an empty line at the end, or similarly at the beginning.  Alternative is, using a late initialized variable (after first use).  So there won't be an empty line at the beginning or the end, but in between groups.

assumes dn is the group starter, will print the first triple until the next dn row comes up.

using your output file

```
dn: cn=default,ou=profile,o=ferry.com
preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.27

dn: cn=austin, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
preferredServerList: 192.68.88.14 10.28.15.10
defaultServerList: 192.68.63.10 10.209.208.23

dn: cn=sanjose, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.38
```

Comment: @karakfa....its working but still printing the "dn" String which don't have other 2 match's ,meaning "dn" also getting printed which i want to avoid..
your awk code always been nice ...

Comment: your expected output has the first group with dn only.  Is it not what you expected?

Comment: @karakfa....sorry for the confusion , that's the output of the command though i don't want "dn" alone if it comes without other 2 searched pattern, saying that only print when it find all three strings "dn" , "preferredServerList" &  "defaultServerList"  all along.

Just edited the post.

Comment: using the code same 3 lines are repeating on the output .

Comment: since don't have access to your original input file, that was guesswork.  I think adding `s=0` after print should fix it.

Comment: apologies i missed  zero in "s=0" . its working fine. I appreciate  if you briefly explain the main code please.  what is sep and "s && !(s%6)" stand here .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`:

```
ldapsearch '...' | grep '...' | sed 's/^dn/\n&/g'
```

Comment: Can we use sed in place of grep for pattrern search itself.. Your sed liner working perfectly..all along i'm looking for awk also as i want to integrate more things with this .

Comment: If you're looking for an awk answer then why tag the question with sed?

Comment: @EdMorton... i believe i taged with awk & sed for both solution , awk preferebly because i want to integrate it with my existing code which is using awk.

Comment: Since you can do anything with awk that you can do with sed, if you prefer an awk solution then there's no need to have people waste their time providing sed solutions which are just going to get thrown away in favor of the awk solution you'll get. Just sayin'....

Comment: @EdMorton    Understand your point.Though as i mentioned even if i'll get a better sed solution i'm okay with that too, So, any one solution would be okay.

Comment: You will not get a better sed than awk solution for any problem that isn't just a simple substitution on individual lines (which your problem is not). As soon as you edit your question to better define your requirements and include concise, testable sample input and expected output I'm sure you will get a simple, robust, efficient awk solution.

Comment: @EdMorton    I'm agree with your point , though i pasted the actual sample output of "ldapsearch" command where if you will see the first string "dn" that do not include other two strings where "dn" is the group starter hence if the "dn" doesn't include other 2 then just don't print it or delete that on the output.

Comment: No, you didn't paste the actual sample output of `ldapsearch`. You pasted the output of `ldapsearch | grep -Ei ...` but you don't want a script to parse the output of `ldapsearch | grep -Ei ...` you want one to parse `ldapsearch` output. So what you've ended up with is an awk script that is based on assumptions/guesses about what the `ldapsearch` output coming into `grep -Ei` might look like and trying to parse that in a way that will work for different variations of what that might be. There may be a better awk solution to parse that actual `ldapsearch` output, whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the point I'm trying to get across wrt why it's important to show the output of `ldapsearch` instead of the output of `ldapseach | grep -Ei...` as the input to the script you want to create, this trivial script will produce the expected output you've shown us from the sample input you've shown us:

```
$ awk '/dn:/{if (cnt==3) print rec; cnt=0; rec=""} {rec = rec $0 ORS; cnt++} END{if (cnt==3) print rec}' file
dn: cn=default,ou=profile,o=ferry.com
preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.27

dn: cn=austin, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
defaultServerList: 192.68.63.10 10.209.208.23
preferredServerList: 192.68.88.14 10.28.15.10

dn: cn=sanjose, ou=profile, o=ferry.com
preferredServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16
defaultServerList: 192.68.8.15 192.68.8.16 192.68.88.38
```

Will it work on the output of `ldapsearch` alone without the `...| grep -Ei...`? Is there an even simpler script that would work on the output of `ldapsearch` alone? I have no idea what the answer is to either question since you haven't shown us what the output of `ldapsearch` alone looks like.

Comment: i have added the actual command output , moreover your code working very nicely the way i asked it.